# How to retrieve an element from this PHP array?

Tags: php, wordpress

So basically I have this array stored in SQL and I'm trying to retrieve the first element from it using PHP

I'm not sure if this is an associative or multidimensional array

```
a:3:{i:0;s:11:"Downpayment";i:1;s:28:"Variable 1 ";i:2;s:28:"Variable 2";}
```

How do I extract elements from this array ?

Comment: are you sure it is the exact data stored in database as its not even proper json

Comment: `s:28` looks wrong for `Variable 1 ` and `Variable 2`... they're neither of them 28 bytes in length

Comment: @MoeenBasra the string is a serialized array, not a `JSON`, check [serialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)

Comment: @MarkBaker is right, the length is wrong, can you post how stored the serialize array in your database ? and the original structure of this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [PHP representation of serialized data](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.serialization.php). Use [`unserialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) on it.

Comment: This worked , thank you so much , i was able to extract it onto an indexed array using serialize()

Answer (score 0):

If you not sure in this array you can use `current()` function or `foreach` to get first element of this array

For set inner pointer on first element use `reset()`